# iphone:significant location update not finding

Tags: iphone

I am using a significant location, but showing update after a long distance.any clue please share.

In `didfinishlaunching` I am starting significant changes and then storing from `didupdatelocation` delegate method of `locationmanager`;

```
id locationValue = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey];
    if(locationValue)
    {NSLog(@"location value is%@",locationValue);
    // create a new manager and start checking for sig changes
    m_locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]
    m_locManager.delegate = self;
    [m_locManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    //[m_locManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self showSplash];
    return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is but I'll tell you a bit about startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

When you use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges you'll only get callbacks when you switch cell towers. So to test that it's working you'll need to drive around or use the location changing stuff the debugger offers.